# Is deleting framaroot app will compromise or delete as well the root permission in my android device?

Tags: rooting

I'm using security as my antivirus, and whenever it updates, ot always scan framaroot app as a virus/riskware. Can I just delete framaroot app in my device and won't compromise my root?

Comment: If a "root access" app is malware, it's beyond hope. It could have written itself into the core of the operating system, in the anti-virus, in anywhere. It's game over. 

However, it's likely that the antivirus just sees that the app uses a security exploit (which is how any app gets root) and suspects it of being a virus.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can safely uninstall Framaroot, without compromising root. Since the file is so small it really isn't necessary.

---

Your " security " app will always detect a virus on an app that roots. Reasoning is it is using an exploit on a vulnerability in the OS.